# Chrome - swipe to dismiss articles on home page missing

Tags: chrome-for-android

As in title

With the latest version `80.0.3987.132`, I noticed you can't swipe to dismiss articles. Instead you need to tap 3 dots menu next to each article and "hide story". Articles also take up much more space then before.

How to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After trying various flags, this worked - enter in address bar

`chrome://flags/#interest-feed-content-suggestions` and in options disable and relaunch chrome

Also see [Chrome - how to swipe to dismiss articles on home page](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/227059/131553) for a fix for version `84.0.4147.89`

Comment: This doesn't work on subsequent versions :(