# Chrome - how to swipe to dismiss articles on home page

Tags: chrome-for-android

[Chrome - swipe to dismiss articles on home page missing](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/222142/131553) answered for previous versions of Chrome. This does not work on Chrome `84.0.4147.89`

Internet search and experiments didn't help. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a shame but you can't do that any more. Google says they won't fix it as mentioned in the  [Chromium bug report](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1060858) ( [Chrome does not maintain separate bug reports](https://support.google.com/chrome/thread/12491762?hl=en))

> Swiping was indeed removed with the latest update due to usability reasons and it being difficult to interpret as a user signal. So this is working as intended.

But an enterprising user found [out a fix!](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1060858#c28) Great!

> Paste `chrome://flags/#interest-feed-content-suggestions` in search bar select Enabled (snippets)

> Paste `chrome://flags/#interest-feed-v2` in search bar and select Enable

> Relaunch Chrome and click on **More** at the bottom of the page.

Now you can swipe away as before. If you care for this feature which Google has removed, please star the bug report and optionally vent your frustration!